# How to import data in a secure way into qlik sense cloud

Tags: qliksense

We are using Qlik Sense Business Cloud and want to import a PostgreSQL database.
Unfortunately the [offical documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/ODBC_connector_help/Content/Connectors_ODBC/PostgresSQL/Create-PostgreSQL-connection.htm#anchor-3) mentions that SSL support is not available for Qlik Sense Cloud.

Is there any way to import data from a database without transferring the data in plain text and the need to configure my SQL server in the most unsecure way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qlik recently released [Qlik Data Transfer](https://www.qlik.com/us/products/qlik-data-transfer). Sounds that it can do the job for you

Havent tried it myself though so cant give more details